# Is there a standard way to denote phrase-oriented comments in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

Imagine, I have a text, which I write in Markdown and then generate HTML out of it using [PegDown](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown).

I want to be able to

- add comments to a chunk of text in MarkDown and
- then generate a document, where I can see the text with the comments.

For example, let's say I have following text:

```
pegdown is nearly 100% compatible with the original Markdown specification and 
fully passes the original Markdown test suite. On top of the standard Markdown 
feature set pegdown implements a number of extensions similar to what other 
popular Markdown processors offer.
```

When I want to add a comment to a part of the text, it may look like this:

```
pegdown is nearly 100% compatible with the [note text="Some note related to that part 
of text"]original Markdown specification[/note] and fully passes the original 
Markdown test suite. On top of the standard Markdown feature set pegdown implements 
a number of extensions similar to what other popular Markdown processors offer.
```

I'm wondering if there is already a standardized way to add notes like these to the text.

The ultimate purpose of this is the ability to edit fiction texts. I'm building a distributed version of [Scrivener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrivener_(software)). Distributed means I can edit the text on any device with Git support (including, but not limited, to my Windows desktop computer and my Android phone with Git client).

Comment: Nope, I'm not aware of any such standard. However, in my experience, any such comment system would normally have the comments stored separate from the document and reference the document by line number or somesuch.

Comment: there is no standard ways in markdown... Pandoc allows footnotes like this`this is a text^[this is a footnote]` which you could then be printed as margin notes with a custom CSS.